# gunicorn process with 100% of CPU after Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade

Tags: 22.04, bug-reporting

I had Ubuntu 20.04 installed and I used the following commands to upgrade it to Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo ppa-purge
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After that I realized there's a `gunicorn` process that consumes 100% of CPU, killing it doesn't solve the problem and I don't know how to debug it. Apparently, Ubuntu 22.04 uses it somehow. Is there anything I could do to fix this problem? I didn't find an easy way of uninstalling it, can I safely uninstall `gunicorn` on Ubuntu 22.04?

---

**Additional information**

I've tried getting additional information of the process but it's constantly changing its `pid`. It's like the process is closing and opening again endlessly. I've seen gunicorn is a python library for web development, but I don't use python for web development in any project. I'm getting worried because my notebook is getting really hot with this process even when I'm doing nothing else with the computer... and I don't know how to stop it. I can't remove it with `apt-get remove gunicorn` , `pip3 uninstall gunicorn`, `pip uninstall gunicorn`, or just `systemctl stop gunicorn`...